# exec error: Error: stdout maxBuffer exceeded if using child_process on Node js

Tags: node.js, linux

I want to get data continuously from monitor processes and system resource usage on Linux using `top` with `child_process.exec`.

Code :

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');
exec('top', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
        console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
        return;
    }
    console.log('stdout', stdout);
    console.log('stderr', stderr);
});
```

If i run code above, i get an error `exec error: Error: stdout maxBuffer exceeded`

I'm using Node.js version v8.9.4

Is possible to get data continuously from `top` command using `child_process.exec`?

Comment: Why not use something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/systeminformation that would probably be tapping into os apis'

Comment: Thank you for your reply.. This link you that you provided just give an information about system, i need to monitor the processes too in real time, so i want to get the data continuously. Any idea?

Comment: a quick look at the docs shows that you can call the `processes(cb)` method repeatedly or with timeout to get the info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `exec` because `top` will never end. Use `spawn` instead and switch `top` to `batch mode`

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const top = spawn('top', ['-b']);

top.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});

top.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stderr: ${data}`);
});

top.on('close', (code) => {
  console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

`exec()` will buffer `stdout`.

> Spawns a shell then executes the command within that shell, buffering any generated output.

([From the docs.](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback))

When `top` is started without further arguments it tries to redraw parts of the terminal. I wonder that you came so far. On my system your code fails with:

> top: failed tty get

You need to tell `top` to run in batch mode so that it will *completely* dump its current state with each update.

```
exec('/usr/bin/top -b', ...);
```

Though since `top` will *dump the states indefinitely* the buffer will still overflow eventually. You could limit the number of updates with the `-n #` switch or use [`spawn()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options):

```
const { spawn } = require("child_process");

// Note: -b for batch mode and -n # for number of updates
let child = spawn("/usr/bin/top", ["-b", "-n", "2"]);

// Listen for outputs
child.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
    console.log(`${data}`);
});
```

Using the `data` listener on the child process' `stdout` stream you can observe the data just in time.